# AsyncResult get() does not return

Tags: python, celery

I am trying to use celery chords and trying to run the following example -

```
@celery.task(ignore_result = False)
def add(x, y):
    return x + y

@celery.task(ignore_result = False)
def tsum(numbers):
    return sum(numbers)

from celery import chord
callback = tsum.s()
header = [add.s(i, i) for i in range(5)]
result = chord(header)(callback)
print result.get()
```

I can see that the tasks all run in the celery logs. However, the line `result.get()` does not return. I have set the `CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = 'amqp://'`

I am very new to celery chords and trying to get this sample program to run first. Am I missing something here.

Following is my celery config-

```
CELERY_BROKER_URL = 'amqp://'
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = 'amqp://'
CELERY_TASK_SERIALIZER = 'json'
CELERY_ACCEPT_CONTENT = ['json']
CELERY_RESULT_SERIALIZER = 'json'
CELERY_ENABLE_UTC = True
```

**EDIT**: adding determining detail!

The problem was fixed, but was totally unrelated with Celery itself. The detail is **The system runs on Microsoft Azure**. I'm adding and accepting the answer. I'm rewarding each kind contribution with a point.

Comment: can you post your celery config?

Comment: @ChillarAnand I have edited the question with my celery config options.

Answer (score 1):

Your `chord` is not getting struck because it is not receiving results from the header and so it cannot start callback function.

Thid is due to your celery config

```
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = 'amqp://'
```

but it should be

```
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = 'amqp'
```

Change that and it should work fine.

Comment: I am getting the same problem. On the celery logs, I can see that `tsum` finishes execution though.

Comment: how you are starting your worker? with `celery worker -l info -A my_app`?

Comment: How can a `://` trigger such a huge difference? This is not documented anywhere AFAIK

Comment: @Dacav http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/configuration.html#celery-result-backend

Answer (score 1):

You really should use something like redis or SQL for the result backend. The [Celery documentation](http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/userguide/tasks.html#rabbitmq-result-backend) notes:

> The RabbitMQ result backend (amqp) is special as it does not actually
>   store the states, but rather sends them as messages. This is an
>   important difference as it means that a result can only be retrieved
>   once; If you have two processes waiting for the same result, one of
>   the processes will never receive the result!

This should work fine for a quick test:

```
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = 'db+sqlite:///results.sqlite'
```

Comment: So even for one process actually receiving the results like in the example above, it still does not get results.

Comment: Not true.  You can change the exchange type to topic.  In fact there are many routing options with the RMQ backend.
http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/userguide/routing.html#topic-exchanges

Answer (score 1):

After trying everything, I decided to try another system entirely, and I moved on [Huey](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/huey/0.4.1). Huey was still failing in the same way, thus the problem was not actually related with *Celery* itself.

Being *Huey* much simpler in the structure, I was able to dig down and I realized that the problem was affecting the *TCP connection of Redis*. A collegue of mine informed me that this happens if you host services on **Microsoft Azure** (which is my case).

**The solution consisted in defining a *TCP keepalive* lower than 5 minutes for the redis connection.**

I applied the trick on *Huey*, where it's just about passing some additional parameter to the constructor. Then I realized *Huey* is good enough, so I never fixed back the *Celery* version. If someone wants to improve this question with an explanation on how to set a keepalive on *Celery*, he or she will be rewarded with acceptance.

Comment: Glad to hear you're liking Huey!

Comment: @coleifer, It has got a simple design, which is something you want if problems arise and you want to put your hands into the code. Celery is probably more supported, but hell, that's tangled!